# ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 9: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation Operation failed with exitcode 1

Tags: mysql

I tried using the mysql pump to create a backup of my MySQL database. When I tried to restore the backup to another server I am getting the error mentioned in the title. I know that question with this error has been asked before but all answers state that I need to delete the `definer` clause from the .sql backup file. However, I do not have a definer word at all in my backup file because I backed up my database doing:

```
mysqlpump --skip-definer -u root -p testempty > c:\users\admin\documents\dumps\backup.sql
```

I searched trough the backup file and there is absolutely no definers at all.

However, the problem is that I am trying to backup and restore to a different database name and my sql contains `database1.tableName` syntax. I am trying to restore to database2

That might be the reason for the problem. I know that if I was using mysqldump instead of mysql pump I could do:

```
mysqldump -u root -p testempty > c:\users\admin\documents\dumps\backup.sql
```

which exports without database name

but mysqldump does not provide skip definer option :(

Why is it such a nightmare to backup and restore mysql database and so easy to do it in MSSQL database? I am trying to streamline my backup and restore process and there are roadblocks everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the database, edited it with notepad++ and after that I deleted "Definer = your username @ local host" and it worked for me.